# Drawing a line where the UIBezierPath gets cut off

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

I'm trying to create a tone curve for an image editing app. I've already create the curve itself, using a UIBezierPath, however, when the curve exceeds the view's bounds, it gets cut off. 
[image: My current tone curve]

Other apps have solved this by drawing a line where the curve gets cut off.
Do you have any idea how to achieve this? A possible way would be to detect where the curve is outside the bounds and draw a line there, but I couldn't find a way to do that.

[image: Other Apps (Pixelmator & Darkroom)]

Comment: Could you please share some code?

Comment: No it is not possible. UIBezier path doesnt repsond if it is interesected with other view.You need a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s not really an easy way to do this. Two options I can think of:

1. Figure out where the curve goes off the edge of the view and draw line segments in the missing areas. This’ll require evaluating a bunch of points along each piece of the curve yourself—the “Cubic Bézier curves” section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_curves) has the formula for that—and storing a list of the X positions where the curve’s Y value goes off the top of the view and where it comes back down again. From there, you can use that list to draw a series of line segments for the off-the-top-of-the-view bits.
2. Make a second version of the curve that loops back around below the bottom of the view via its corners, assign that to a shape layer that has a fill color set, and mask that with a thin layer (with height equal to your line thickness) running along the top of the view. This won’t necessarily look as nice as the other approach, since the ends of the thin line layer will overlap with bits of the curve, but it’s a lot less math work. In the diagram below, on the left is the original path; after that is that path with an additional point added for the lower-right corner of your view, after which you’d close the path (with `-closePath`); assigning that to a CAShapeLayer and setting its fill color (blue), then setting that layer as the mask of a thin rectangular layer positioned at the top of the view (green), gives you a layer that is visible anywhere your curve crosses the top of your view.
   [image: curve masking diagram]